# Server hardware for moodle with 30000 users

Tags: moodle

I would like to ask if moodle can handle 30000 total users, and 5000 concurent users.

If yes, what hardware would you suggest.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

One of my clients has over 300,000 users. They use Microsoft Azure Cloud. Other clients use Amazon Web Services.

On the Moodle stats page, there are 7 sites with over 1m users

https://stats.moodle.org/

Moodle also has their own cloud, but you will need to contact them for that number of users.

https://moodlecloud.com/